# how Javascript use in tic tak o

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

Description

You are given a 3 * 3matrix(2d-array) that represents the final situation of a Tic Tac Toe.

Your task is to write a program that finds out the winner in case the match ended in a win. If the winner is 'x', printx.

If the winner is 'o', printo.

In case the match ended in a tie, printTie.

Input
InputFormat

The input contains 3 lines where each line has 3 space separated characters which represent the final status of tic tac toe

Constraints

The input contains either of the 2 alphabets: 'x' and 'o'

Output
Print Tie/x/o depending on the end result of the game.

Sample Input 1

x o x
o x x
o o o
Sample Output 1

o`
Hint

owins as per tic tac toe.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a task solving service. This is a Q&A site where specific programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get specific answers. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and carefully read through the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn more about the site, including [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), as well as [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](/help/dont-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 0):

Well here's one I made when I was 12 years old.

It might not be the most efficient but I think it works.

I changed a few bits to fit your task a bit better. If you want me to walk through it for you or make it more efficient, you can ask.

```
function tickTackToe(inp) {
    const arr = inp.split(" ");
    const matrix = [arr.slice(0, 3),
                    arr.slice(3, 6),
                    arr.slice(6, 9)]
    var numberCorrect = 0
    function checkIsSame(player, position, direction) {
        var newPosition = position;
        if (direction === "right") newPosition[0]++
        else if (direction === "down") newPosition[1]++
        else if (direction === "downright"){
            newPosition[0]++;
            newPosition[1]++;
        }
        else if (direction === "upright"){
            newPosition[0]++;
            newPosition[1]--;
        }
        if (newPosition[0] <= 2 && newPosition[0] >= 0 && newPosition[1] <= 2 && newPosition[1] >= 0) {
            if (matrix[newPosition[0]][newPosition[1]] == player) {
                numberCorrect++
                checkIsSame(player, newPosition, direction)
            }
        }
        else if (numberCorrect == 2) return true
        else {
            numberCorrect = 0
            return false
        }
    }

    const directions = ["right", "down", "downright", "upright"];
    for (let i=0;i<matrix[0].length;i++) {
        for (let j=0;j<directions.length;j++) if (checkIsSame(matrix[0][i], [0, i], directions[j])) return matrix[0][i];
    }
    numberCorrect = 0
    for (let i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
        for (let j=0;j<directions.length;j++) if (checkIsSame(matrix[i][0], [i, 0], directions[j])) return matrix[i][0];
    }
    return "draw"
}
```